# Overwrite with SP.MoveCopyUtil

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, copy-item

I can't get the overwrite paramreter in SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile to work. I can't find any good documentation on it either. Heres the code.

```
appObj.copyFile = function (source, path, fileName) {
var fileParts = path.split(/\//);
fileParts.shift();
var destination = fileParts.join('/'), sourceParts = source.split(/\//);
sourceParts.shift();
var src = sourceParts.join('/'), 
    time = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 0 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toLocaleTimeString(),
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appObj.appWebUrl),
factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appObj.appWebUrl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, appObj.hostweburl);
this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
context.load(this.web);
console.log(appObj.host + source + '/' + fileName, appObj.host + destination + '/' + fileName);
SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context, (appObj.host + source + '/' + fileName), (appObj.host + '/' + destination + '/' + fileName), true);
context.executeQueryAsync(function (a, b) {
    var html;
    html = String.format("<p>{0}: <br> File: {1} copied from {2} <br> to  {3}</p>", time, fileName, source + '/' + fileName, destination + '/' + fileName);
    console.log(html);
    $("#logBox").append(html);
},
function (a, b) {
    var html,
        message = b.get_message();
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    html = String.format("<p>{0}:</p><p>Error: {1}</p>", time, message);
    console.log(html);
    $("#logBox").append(html);
});
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Typing SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile in the console gives me some information:

```
    function SP_MoveCopyUtil$copyFile(context, srcUrl, destUrl, overwrite)
```

Comment: Could you please paste full URLs of the source and destination variables

Comment: It works with copying files, so the URLs are correct. It's the overwrite parameter that doesn't work. But sure, I can post them if the formating of the URL has an impact on the overwrite parameter.

Comment: Source URL: https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/subsite/subsubsite/doclib2/Book.xlsx Destination: https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/subsite/subsubsite/doclib2/Book.xlsx

Comment: Looks like the source and destination URLs are the same

Comment: exactly. I get file already exsists error, but I want to overwrite

Comment: And the parameter is set to true

Answer (score 1):

Please see an example below:

```
(function(from, to){
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context, from, to, true);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ console.log("The file was copied successfully"); },
        function(s,a){console.log(a.get_message());}
    );
})("https://test.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Test%20File%20A4.pdf", "https://test.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Test%20File%20A4_2.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you, but this seems like exactly what I've done. Let me update my post to include all of the code, maybe you can spot what I'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.movecopyutil.copyfile?view=sharepoint-csom#microsoft-sharepoint-client-movecopyutil-copyfile(microsoft-sharepoint-client-clientruntimecontext-system-string-system-string-system-boolean-microsoft-sharepoint-client-movecopyoptions))

The C# code on documentation shows that overwrite can be used. Therefore, we can use overwrite in JavaScript as well.

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Remote]
public static void CopyFile (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext context, string srcUrl, string destUrl, bool overwrite, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions options);
```